# Plixi Upload Photo

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

In my App, upload photo using plixi api its possible or not. Anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plixi API is REST-based, so yes, it should be entirely possible to use it within your app, provided that the user has an active network connection.

Comment: I am using This link.http://groups.google.com/group/plixi/web/basic-upload-api-v2-0-upload-and-uploadandpost

Comment: That should work fine, you just need to construct and send a POST request to `http://api.plixi.com/api/tpapi.svc/upload2`.  For doing that, you may want to consult the [NSUrlRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

Comment: i got this error: Response <TweetPhotoResponse xmlns="http://tweetphotoapi.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Error><ErrorCode>1009</ErrorCode><Message>Invalid api key or key no longer in use please contact administrator</Message></Error><Status>fail</Status></TweetPhotoResponse>

Comment: Sounds like you need to double-check your API key.

Comment: Ya i check it well but it says same result